# c++ string to utf8 valid string using utf8proc

Tags: c++, string, utf-8

I have a std::string output. Using utf8proc i would like to transform it into an valid utf8 string.
http://www.public-software-group.org/utf8proc-documentation

```
typedef int int32_t;
#define ssize_t int
ssize_t utf8proc_reencode(int32_t *buffer, ssize_t length, int options)
Reencodes the sequence of unicode characters given by the pointer buffer and length as UTF-8. The result is stored in the same memory area where the data is read. Following flags in the options field are regarded: (Documentation missing here) In case of success the length of the resulting UTF-8 string is returned, otherwise a negative error code is returned.
WARNING: The amount of free space being pointed to by buffer, has to exceed the amount of the input data by one byte, and the entries of the array pointed to by str have to be in the range of 0x0000 to 0x10FFFF, otherwise the program might crash!
```

So first, how do I add an extra byte at the end? Then how do I convert from std::string to int32_t *buffer?

This does not work:

```
std::string g = output();
fprintf(stdout,"str: %s\n",g.c_str());
g += " ";   //add an extra byte?? 
g = utf8proc_reencode((int*)g.c_str(), g.size()-1, 0);
fprintf(stdout,"strutf8: %s\n",g.c_str());
```

Comment: `std::string` is just a sequence of bytes. What encoding is your source `std::string` in?

Comment: I cringe everytime I see `printf` in a C++ program, especially outputting strings.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: the output is not always the same encoding. usually it is utf8, but sometimes it is some encoding i do now know.

Comment: "sometimes it is some encoding i do now know" - you have a fundamental problem that you cannot solve by blindly throwing code at it. You *need* to know what encoding your string is in before you can sensibly convert it to any other encoding.

Comment: i do not know it since i read from iptc data...

Comment: I don't know what "iptc data" is.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC-NAA-Standard

Answer (score 0):

You very likely don't actually want `utf8proc_reencode()` - that function takes a valid UTF-32 buffer and turns it into a valid UTF-8 buffer, but since you say you don't know what encoding your data is in then you can't use that function.

So, first you need to figure out what encoding your data is actually in. You can use http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ to test whether you already have valid UTF-8 with `utf8::is_valid(g.begin(), g.end())`. If that's true, you're done!

If false, things get complicated...but ICU ( http://icu-project.org/ ) can help you; see http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion/detection

Once you somewhat reliably know what encoding your data is in, ICU can help again with getting it to UTF-8. For example, assuming your source data `g` is in ISO-8859-1:
`UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR; // check this after every call...
// CONVERT FROM ISO-8859-1 TO UChar
UConverter *conv_from = ucnv_open("ISO-8859-1", &err);
std::vector<UChar> converted(g.size()*2); // *2 is usually more than enough
int32_t conv_len = ucnv_toUChars(conv_from, &converted[0], converted.size(), g.c_str(), g.size(), &err);
converted.resize(conv_len);
ucnv_close(conv_from);
// CONVERT FROM UChar TO UTF-8
g.resize(converted.size()*4);
UConverter *conv_u8 = ucnv_open("UTF-8", &err);
int32_t u8_len = ucnv_fromUChars(conv_u8, &g[0], g.size(), &converted[0], converted.size(), &err);
g.resize(u8_len);
ucnv_close(conv_u8);`

after which your `g` is now holding UTF-8 data.